# Is there a way I can change a Select2 option by changing the v-model?

Tags: vue.js, jquery-select2

I've been using [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fgpdp700/5/) example to integrate select2 and Vue. So far it's been great, but the issue I'm having now is that I want to be able to change the v-model value by means of a method, and when I do it should reflect on the select2 element. But it doesn't. In that fiddle I tried adding the following code in the addOption method: `this.optionArr[0].id = 2`

Pressing the button does change the value, but the select2 element stays the same. Is there anyway I can change the value in the select2 as well? I should add that my select2 doesn't have static options. They are loaded by ajax when the select2 is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    value: function (value) {
      // update value
      $(this.$el).val(value)
    },
```

to

```
    value: function (value) {
      // update value
      $(this.$el).val(value).trigger('change.select2')
    },
```